# H1B Visa interview in India

Tags: visas, india, visa-extensions, h1b-visas, interview

Good morning.

I am trying to schedule the interview for my H1B visa extension during my next vacation to India.
I am using this link -  https://evisaforms.state.gov/Instructions/SchedulingSystem.asp

But unfortunately, I am not seeing India in the country list.

Can you please let me know if I am on the right page? If not, can you please send me the right URL to schedule the interview?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use this website: https://www.usvisascheduling.com/

Found via https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/, which links to https://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/en/ which is weirdly enough not a .gov website, but is an official website.